# Not able to get NSDate from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I tried executing the following code to get a date from an `NSString`:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"GMT"]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"];

NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2015-01-18T09:33:49.699-0600"];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Why am I receiving `nil` value?

Comment: See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)  
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Comment: @Rob - further more, `GMT` isn't a locale, it's a timezone.

Comment: @rmaddy Quite right. Actually for RFC 3339 / ISO 8601 dates, he _should_ specify locale, but he should be using `en_US_POSIX`, as outlined in [TN1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). Using `GMT` here makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string should be

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Note the upper case `.SSS`.

---

And for the locale, you should specify `@"en_US_POSIX"` as advised in [Technical Note TN1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). This will ensure that you can successfully parse this RFC 3339/ISO 8601 formatted date, regardless of the user's localization settings.